# Test string equality in R where strings are in different orders

Tags: r, string, stringr

I want to consider the following two strings as equal

```
s1 = "thisissomething"
s2 = "somethingisthis"
```

How do I test for this using R?

Comment: how do you define equality? Is there a way to use The Levenshtein distance?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the two strings in alphabetical order and compare them

Comment: sure - how. In python this is just `''.join(sorted(string))`

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))`

Comment: This could be a complete answer if it included an idea for writing this code. Right now it's just a suggestion that's more appropriate as a comment.